# How to only show transactions between a specified date range in GnuCash?

Tags: taxes, gnucash

I'm still new to GnuCash so please bear with me: My business has year end 03/31 and I was wondering if I can select a date range so that it shows me transactions within the range?

Or am I supposed to start with a new file for every year? (When reporting taxes, I want to only report the numbers from within that previous year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to look for transactions within a date range, you probably want to run a Report to do so. Gnucash seems to be organized around the concept of using the registers primarily for entry (although they do have some filtering and search capabilities), but to use a Report when you want to see information or get an export for tax documentation purposes.

I would recommend looking at the documentation on [Reports](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.6/C/gnucash-guide/ch_reports.html), and particularly try out the [Transaction Report](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.6/C/gnucash-guide/rpt_standardrpts.html#rpt_grp_miscrpts) to see a list of transactions for a particular date range. That's what I use to export a list of transactions to put totals on my tax returns.

You may also want to look at [setting your accounting period](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v2.6/C/gnucash-help/set-prefs.html#prefs-accounting-period), if it doesn't follow a typical calendar year.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much possible to limit transactions shown between dates. For the following screenshots I am using the [reg_doc_example.gnucash](https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash/blob/unstable/doc/examples/reg_doc_example.gnucash) file. After importing it and opening the general ledger (menu *Tools* -> *General ledger*) it will display nothing:

[image: screenshot empty ledger]

but if you select menu *Edit* -> *Filter by*, and chose a start date early 2001 or before

[image: screenshot filter menu]

then the ledger will show all the transactions:

[image: screenshot ledger with transactions]

Comment: But this shows each transaction as a separate entry and I'd want to see it all bundled into the account it is associated with...just like in the original _Accounts_ tab, is that possible too?